# I want to make a mouse look script, that moves my head, then at a point, moves my whole body. I can't figure it out

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, controller, mouse

I want to create a script, which controls my camera using my mouse, like a basic MouseLook script. But, I want the camera to move with the head, and when the head reaches a specific angle, I want the whole body to move... I can't figure it out. I have been using Unity for more then a year now, trying to finish this since MONTHS. I think it's about time I learn something more advanced. Any help appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Can you show some code to let us see what have you done so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And 7 months later, I'M BACK!

```
public GameObject playerHead;
public GameObject character;

void Update()
{
    //check if the head is at a specific angle and if the mouse is moving
    if (playerHead.transform.localRotation.x >= 0.59f && Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") < 0) {
        //rotate the body at the speed of the mouse
        transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"), 0));
    //repeat
    } else if (playerHead.transform.localRotation.x <= -0.59f && Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") > 0) {
        transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"), 0));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution:
*(I guess that moving the camera == moving the head in your project)*

You can get relative angle between head `Transform.eulerAngles` and body `Transform.eulerAngles` just using `Vector3.Angle` (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Angle.html)
Then, in the `Update` method you can rotate your body manually, for example, `Rigidbody.MoveRotation` (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MoveRotation.html).

You can also lerp this rotation to make it smoothly.
*(I can help you more presizeliy if you add some code)*